# Changing All Icons Rotating Down to One

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typescript

I currently have a giant table of "auditpoints", some of those points are "automated".  If they are automated they receive a gear icon in their row.  The gear icon is not the only icon each row receives.  Each row, no matter if it's automated or not receives two other icons, a pencil and a toggle button.  When an automated point "runs" the gear icon rotates until it is finished "running".  I've have implemented some code to ran all of these points at once but I have a small problem.  When you click my button to run all these points all three of the icons I have mentioned rotate and this is not the result I am looking for.  The line commented out in my code snippet (and it's matching bracket) will prevent the code from running all of the automated points.  Commenting out the line is what causes all the icons to rotate.  I know this line is required to get the automated points to run properly as it used in the single execution of automated points I just don't know what to change it to.  It obviously shouldn't be click because you are no longer clicking the gear icon to get a point to run I just don't know what to change it to but the classes in that click function are related to the gear icon.

Hopefully this is a very easy question to solve and doesn't waste anyone's time.  Thank you!

```
private updateAuto() {
        var self = this;
        $(".auditPointRow").each(function () {
            //self.el.on("click", ".update, .edit", function () {                    
                var row = $(this).closest(".auditPointRow");
                var id = row.data("id");
                var automated = (<string>row.data("automated")).toLowerCase() == "true";
                var running = true;
                if (automated && $(this).closest(".edit").length == 0) {
                    var gear = $(this).find(".fa");
                    var maxTurns = 120;
                    gear.css("transition", "transform linear " + maxTurns * 2 + "s");
                    gear.css("transform", "rotate(" + (maxTurns * 360) + "deg)");
                    var request = $.ajax(self.root + "api/sites/" + self.site.ID + "/auditpoints/" + id, {
                        "type": "PATCH", data: JSON.stringify([
                            {
                                Op: "Replace"
                                , Path: "/score"
                                , Value: "run"
                            }
                        ])
                    });
                    request.done(function () {
                        gear.css("transition", "").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
                        row.prev().find("td").css("background-color", "");
                        if (row.prev().qtip("api")) {
                            row.prev().qtip("api").destroy(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            //}
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is really overkill.. Simply applying a rotating CSS class and removing would suffice.. No ?

Comment: @Pogrindis There's some other stuff that's going on there that I decided not to mention because it's not relevant to the rotating issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my problem.  I used `.each` again to go through all of the "gears" and only rotate them.

```
private updateAuto() {
    var self = this;
    //$(".auditPointRow").each(function () {
        $(".update, .edit").each(function () {                    
              //Left out the rest of the code so this answer isn't too 
              //long, none of it changed if that matters.
        });
    //});
}
```

For some reason the result runs very slowly (but it runs!) and I'm not sure why so if anyone has any better suggestion/optimizations please feel free to leave those here.

Edit: I realized I didn't to go through `.each` twice, that's what was slowing to down so I removed that first each that went over auditPoints and just did the ones with gears instead.